# How to prevent use of the first row Pandas DataFrame as column names when using to_sql

Tags: mysql, csv, pandas

I have a dataframe loaded from a CSV file, which includes a header row. After assigning the returned dataframe from read_csv, I'm trying to add the rows to a MySQL database table using SQLAlchemy engine, my method call looks like this:

```
my_dataframe.to_sql(name="my_table",
                    con=alch_engine,
                    if_exists="append",
                    chunksize=50,
                    index=False,
                    index_label=None)
```

However, the table already exists, and the values of the dataframe header don't match the column names, and so I get a MySQL error (1054, "Unknown Column 'Col1' in 'field_list'")

I would like not to use the first row at all and run the insert query without specifying the column names. I have not found a solution for this from the Pandas manual.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot do that with `.to_sql()`. But you can modify the dataframe to match the column names in the table. Provided `db_cols` is a list/array/series/iterable containing the names, this should do:

```
(my_dataframe
 .rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, db_cols)))
 .to_sql(name="my_table",
         con=alch_engine,
         if_exists="append",
         chunksize=50,
         index=False,
         index_label=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Old.. but came across this.. far as i know, when you create the dataframe in the first place, you can specify header=None.. then the dataframe has no column names and the first row is treated as data.
i've only used it for excel.. but i assume csv is the same:

`my_dataframe = pd.read_csv(full_path, header=None)`

Then when you use to_sql, it won't have the column names. it seems then pandas attempts to use numbers as the column names for it's insert statement. I suppose it depends on the db engine to accept that as valid.
ie it generates something like:

`INSERT INTO [table] (`0`,` 1`) VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s)`

[sorry, not sure how to escape the quote in this comment box to show them around the column names above]

Answer (score -1):

Found out a simple way out for this problem.

First, read the very first line i.e. the header and save it as a list(header_list).

Second, create a Dataframe without skipping any rows. Do not use the names argument.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(input_file, quotechar='"', skiprows = skip_row_count, nrows = num_of_lines_per_iter)
```

This will create the table with the first row as Table Header and insert the rest of the rows as data.

Third, if the table exists, create a data frame, this time use the names argument.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(input_file, quotechar='"', skiprows=skip_row_count, nrows=num_of_lines_per_iter, names = header)
```

This will ensure the data in the data frame is inserted into the corresponding columns by matching the column names in data frame against the column names in the table.

Finally, you can use skiprows argument to skip the header.